# How to select default application

Tags: default-applications

How can I change the default application for a given file type or protocol?
For example, I have multiple browsers on my smartphone and have selected "Internet" (the default browser) to be "the default browser" because it kept asking on every link.

How can I change that to ask me each time or at least select a different option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to:

```
Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All -> Web [or Internet]
```

Hit "Clear Defaults" and that will change it to again ask every time.