# Tapped Always instead of Once

Tags: sms, default-applications

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but I accidentally tapped "always" to choose the app when I meant to tap "once" (in text messaging).  How do change it?

I tried to tap "Clear Defaults", as referenced in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/how-to-change-a-default-application-in-ice-cream-sandwich), but I can't.

Comment: Other questions that may be relevant include [How do I change the default SMS application on my HTC Hero?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2509) and [How to select default application](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4279)

Comment: As your question got closed: I see how your problem is different, and added an [appropriate alternative](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/37651/16575) to the linked "duplicate". Please check it out, I'm sure it solves your issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate a little bit on why you can't use "Clear Defaults", then. Is the button grayed out? Something else entirely? On ICS or later you can also clear out *all* app defaults in one shot if you wanted to go that route (and had a recent enough device; see [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29540/clear-default-not-enabled-in-4-0) for more on that one).

Comment: When you have to choose "once" double tap the app icon instead.